# How to backup some selected tables, but not all, in pgAdmin 4?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

In pgAdmin 3, the dialog to perform a backup allowed you to check and un-check the tables you wanted to be part of your backup.

In pgAdmin 4, either I am unable to find this feature, or it is not there.

**Is there any method of backing up only a selection of tables in pgAdmin 4?**

Comment: Right now it is not possible to take backup selected tables from a schema, you have to take individual backup of each table separately.

Comment: @mg1075 You may refer the link as below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48157200/4511992

Comment: The option to include a selection of your tables is possible using [DBEAVER](https://dbeaver.com/), via 'Database/Tools/Backup'

Answer (score 1):

You can backup a single table, a schema, or a complete database. Choose the database object which contains all tables. `Right click`> `Backup`. In the backup dialog, choose `Table Options` tab. There is a field `Exclude table data`. Then enter unwanted table names (maybe **pattern**).

[image]

Reference: [Backup Dialog](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/backup_dialog.html)